# I want to use inline validation function in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp

hear is the code

```
<spring:form modelAttribute="commonBean" action="saveStock.htm">
<div class="content" align="center">
            <div class="box"><br>
                <h1>
        <spring:label path=""> Stock  Entry</spring:label>

                </h1><br><hr>
        <table>

    <tr>
    <th align='left'><spring:label path="">Item Name: </spring:label>
                    </th>
    <td colspan='5'><spring:input path="" ></spring:input>
        <span style="font-style: italic;color: red;">
        <spring:errors path="" id="iname" onkeyup="iname()">
        <img src="green.png" class="def" id="iname_true"/>
    <img src="cross.png" class="def" id="iname_false"/>
         </spring:errors></span>
    </td>

       </tr>
```

and its giving error like

HTTP ERROR: 500

/WEB-INF/jsp/corefiles/stock.jsp(19,22) PWC6239: According to TLD, tag spring:input must be empty, but is not

Plz some one suggest me how to achive that

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<spring:input path="" ></spring:input>
```

to:

```
<spring:input path="CommonBeanPropertyName" />
```

You have to set a path, so that Spring will be able to bind the input field to the corresponding bean property.

Have a look to the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input) .